# Pandas Dataframe wrangling - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` like below:

```
ID Emp1  Emp2 Emp3

1  John NaN Alex

2  John Steve Alex

3  John Steve Alex

4  Clint Jorge NaN
```

I would like to convert the above dataframe into something like this:

```
John Emp1 [1,2,3]
Clint Emp1 [4] 
Steve Emp2 [2,3]
Jorge Emp2 [4]
Alex Emp3 [1,2]
```

So, basically for each column (Emp1, Emp2, Emp3), find "unique" values (drop NaN) and for each unique value, get "ID's" and "column name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to `melt` your data to get into long-format. Then you'll need to perform a groupby aggregation to condense down your "name" and "Emp" data:

```
new_df = (df
 .melt(id_vars="ID", var_name="emp", value_name="name")
 .dropna()
 .groupby(["name", "emp"], as_index=False)
 .agg(list)
 .sort_values(["emp", "name"], ascending=[True, False])
)

print(new_df)
    name   emp         ID
1  Clint  Emp1        [4]
2   John  Emp1  [1, 2, 3]
3  Jorge  Emp2        [4]
4  Steve  Emp2     [2, 3]
0   Alex  Emp3  [1, 2, 3]
```